# ploting pie chart using groupby function in pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pie-chart

I am trying to plot a pie chart as a result of the function groupby on dataframe.

I am able to return the correct result of the **groupby function** but when o try to plot the pie chart its doesn't display all the result.

## code:

```
tl = pd.unique(df['event_type'].tolist())

th = pd.unique(df['event_mohafaza'].tolist())

ct = df.groupby(['event_mohafaza','event_type']).aggregate('sum')

ct = ct.reset_index()
ct['labels'] = df['event_mohafaza'] + ' ' + df['event_type']

trace = go.Pie(labels=ct['labels'], 
                hoverinfo='label+percent', 
                values=ct['number_person'], 
                textposition='outside',                
                rotation=90)
layout = go.Layout(
                   title="Percentage of events",
                   font=dict(family='Arial', size=12, color='#909090'),
                   legend=dict(x=0.9, y=0.5)
                    )
data = [trace]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

result of the groupby function:

```
                                 number_person
event_mohafaza event_type                     
loc1           swimming                9157
               football                690
               baseball                2292

loc2           swimming               10560
               football               8987
               baseball               70280
              
loc3           basketball             130
               swimming               19395
               football               5370
               baseball               19078
              
loc4           swimming               9492
               football               50
               baseball               5279

loc5           swimming               4652
               football               2215
               baseball               3000
```

the plotted  pie chart:

it doesn't display all the values  it must divide the pie into **16 pieces** where now its divided into **8 pieces**

[image]

Comment: can youi provide your data, or some sample data please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```py
values = ct['number_person'].value_counts()
```